# I need the recommendations of the open source educational system that helps to keep the track of student's progress

Tags: web-apps, crm

Could you please recommend me a system (an open-source web application) which can handle the works like:

1. Student enrollment - name, college, citizenship certificate, Area of interest (courses)
2. Add courses
3. Progress tracking

   a. What courses they attended.

   b. Which courses they completed.

   c. What certifications they achieved.
4. Track if the students reached up to job placements.

Comment: That's what you want it to _do_. But what is this _for_?

Comment: Are you simply tracking that information, or are you actually delivering the courses as well?

Comment: deliver the courses and track the progress of the students as per the courses taken.